# Strange characters appearing in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, snow-leopard

When using Terminal, I sometimes get the following appearing.

```
Last login: Fri Dec 27 22:04:56 on ttys002
ޕ:~ agrimm$ cd ruby
ޕ:ruby agrimm$ cd ..
ޕ:~ agrimm$ cd ruby/
ޕ:ruby agrimm$ pwd
/Users/agrimm/ruby
ޕ:ruby agrimm$
```

With the following screenshot (in which it can be seen that the order of text isn't correct)

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using "Default login shell" in my Terminal settings.

The files mentioned in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/8458/691) seem normal. /etc/profile seems normal. ~/.bash_profile seems normal apart from rbenv, homebrew, and Java stuff:

```
# Commented out lines not included
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6 -a x86_64`
```

~/.bash_login doesn't exist

~/.profile seems fairly normal:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2009-12-30_at_14:40:02: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

I'm using Snow Leopard. `uname -a` gives the following:

```
Darwin ޕ 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

The problem seems to occasionally appear and disappear.

How do I fix the strange characters and the order of text being wrong?

Comment: Have you gone into Preferences and tried out a different font? (Nice hat, by the way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the name of the volume is causing the issue. Normally the prompt would be like:

```
$ cd ~
volume:~ user$ 

$ cd /
volume:/ user$
```

Your prompt appears similar, but like this:

```
ޕ:~ agrimm$
```

Which leads me to believe the volume has an odd character in it's name.

Comment: Yes. Turning off my wireless network changed the name of my Volume, making it normal again, and even when I turned it back on, it remained normal.